# Asp.net Web Api Redirect request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I have an Asp.net Web API project which has several CRUD methods.

On top of these methods, i want to add an Authorization service that reads the `Authorization` header and prevent users of accessing the resources (if they are not authorized).

```
// Method on internal IP Project
public class InternalController : ApiController
{
    public void Create(CreateRequest request)
    {
        // implement the method
    }
}

// Method on public IP Project
public class ExternalController : ApiController
{
    public async Task Create(CreateRequest request)
    {
        // validate Authorization header and throw exception if not valid

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string parameters = string.Format("param1={0}&param2={1}", request.Param1, request.Param2);

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.1/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/internal/create?" + parameters);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way of "Redirecting" the request from the External API to the Internal API more easily?

Right now, i have to manually re-create all the parameters that i receive in ExternalAPI and send them in the InternalAPI, even if they are the same.

Can i make `HttpClient` automatically send the `HttpRequestMessage (Request)` object that i have in ExternalAPI method?

Comment: Are `InternalController` and `ExternalController` on the same web project?

Comment: No, they are different projects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**When speaking about ASP.NET Web API**. HttpClient will not automatically redirect you. When you have become response from internal service you can pass it to external. Or you can redirect your action like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737040/use-redirecttoaction-in-web-api)

To make it correct redirection for client from REST point of view use HTTP Redirect Headers and repsonse codes. For example [HTTP response code 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302). And then client should be able to react on such response code and get redirect address from Location header. But it's about redirect for client.

**When speaking about call of some internal services from your API from architecture**. You have following alternatives:

1. Call your internal service as class method
2. Make service to service call
3. Setup message queue or bus and your API will communicate with it through service bus.

**Call your internal service as class method**
Very easy. No impact and delays for service call. But you should reference assembly and it's not always possible. Or such way could be not possible due to requirements

**Make service to service call**
Has disadvantages: your services are tightly coupled, you have delay and should wait for response from internal service. It's considered as bad practice. But could be a good temporarily solution as first step to service bus.

**Setup message queue or bus and your API will communicate with it through service bus.**
Your services are decoupled and independent. You shouldn't wait for response. But it's technically harder to set up and make your architecture and infrastructure more complex/

**As summary**
There is no best way from the box for your architecture and you should select from alternatives based on your requirements.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer! I think i will go using the Service class, also because i can reference the assemblies i need.

Answer (score 0):

***Here is the sample code to Post the data to web api:-***

```
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler {UseDefaultCredentials = true};
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {   
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://IE url.com");  
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var  postDataObject = new
                {
                    SCName = properties.Site.PortalName,
                    TotalSites = properties.Web.Webs.Count
     };

    var jsonPostData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(postDataObject);
                HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonPostData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("/controllerclassname/InsertUpdateDataOperation", content).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
        //Check the response here
                  //  var webApiResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;                    
                }
```