# How to Redirect in ASPNET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is there a Web API controller method equivalent to the MVC controller method RedirectToAction? I would like to call one method from another, but retain the filter actions for the secondary method.

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295597/asp-net-web-api-redirect-request

Comment: The different actions have different parameters.  How would I be able to set the parameters on the secondary action using a header based redirect?

Making a direct class call would not allow me to make use of the existing action filters.

Or am I approaching this incorrectly?  Should I instead be looking to custom routing, instead?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Is there a Web API controller method equivalent to the MVC controller method RedirectToAction?

You could set the Location header:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: The two actions have different parameters.  How would I be able to set the values for the parameters for the secondary action using the header redirect?

Comment: Just use the `Url` helper: `response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { foo = "bar" }));`.

Comment: This was very close to satisfying my needs.  My case, however, requires the variable to be a POST.  If that were not the case, this solution would prove very interesting (though WebAPI doesn't have Url.Action).  Nonetheless, this is by far the best answer....

Answer (score 6):

**You can check this for redirecting a page from a controller in web api**

```
[Route("Report/MyReport")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> getReport() {

    string url = "https://localhost:44305/Templates/ReportPage.html";

    System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(url);

    return Redirect(uri);
}
```

Comment: `Edit` your last answer rather than `posting a new one`

Comment: i have deleted that.