# Post and redirect FROM Web Api

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, http-post, dotnet-httpclient

**Warning:**
This question is NOT about How to post TO a Web Api, is How to post FROM Web Api.

### Scenario:

My question is related to the comments of the answer of Darin Dimitrov in:
[How to Redirect in ASPNET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347625/how-to-redirect-in-aspnet-web-api)

and is seems to be a duplicated for: [Response.Redirect which POSTs data to another URL in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062078/response-redirect-which-posts-data-to-another-url-in-asp-net/6062248#6062248)
but take in consideration that the question is already old (2008) and I'm looking for answer that maybe WebApi is up to date.

> Using Visual Studio 2012 Web Api 2.1

I've get from data in my application (is a web api) trough a POST method in a controller. So far so good. Now I want to post this data (with some changes) to an external site that accepts my data (this is validated and works).

For this process I've tried two methods:

1. Make a string with a basic form that submit with a "onload" event with javascript.
   From ([Response.Redirect which POSTs data to another URL in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062078/response-redirect-which-posts-data-to-another-url-in-asp-net/6062248#6062248)). This is working, and this is how I'm using it, but maybe can be replaced with some better approach.
2. With an `HTTPClient` using `client.PostAsync` . I could also work with this, but I don't want show the response to the user, I want to redirect him. Maybe can be this adapted to make a redirect?

### Question:

How do I redirect sending Post variables without using the "onload" workaround or adapting the "HttpClient" to make a post-redirection without waiting for response ?

Consideration: I don't post any code because implementations of my two options are already easy and I don't have any trouble with them.

Comment: I think the options you have explored (redirecting via client-side form with onLoad submission, or server-side async redirection) are the only viable methods if you want to modify the POST data before the redirect. If you didn't need to alter the data, you could issue a 307 response to the client with the external API in the Location header (which should redirect the POST request), but not all browsers respond to 307 responses correctly.

Comment: Thanks Rudism, I hope you are wrong... :(

Comment: This is still a requirement in 2018 and still no way that I can find of doing it without using any of the above mentioned hacks.