# How can I get the url of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, cors

How can I get the `URL` of an iframe **that load a page in other site (CORS)**?

```
iFrameObject.contentWindow.location.href
```

returns `CORS Error`

**UPDATE:**

The user will navigate inside the iframe and will get another url that I didn't know. This is what I want to check, if the user gets to that url, the iframe close itself.

Related question:
[How to get data from an external site inside a cordova application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023089/how-to-get-data-from-an-external-site-inside-a-cordova-application) (I'm trying to get the information in the paramters of the url)

Comment: The guy who flag and downvote, didn't read the "duplicated" question (That is my own question!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get it's `src` property:

```
var URL = iFrameObject.src;
// something like "http://example.com"
```

**UPDATE:** Since that the URL of the frame will change and become different from the `src` property, you'll not be able to access it without violating the Cross-Origin policy. You cannot perform any action in an `iframe` that has got another origin.

Comment: Your answer returns everytime the SRC, not the url.

Comment: Then you'll have to use the contentWindow, but you can't do it because of the CORS error... you've to work around and find another solution rather than an iframe

Comment: So there is no answer to this question?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is that you cannot obtain the url of an external frame

Comment: Thanks. Please edit your answer and add this last comment to the bottom of your answer, in order to future people get it quickly.