# Web API redirect to view with model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-web-api

How can I redirect from api method to some View with some model?
This is as in the standart controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("View",model).
```

Can I make something like this in a method of ApiController?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use RedirectToAction in Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11737040/217324) ?

Answer (score 0):

You usually invoke Web API using AJAX. For example using jQuery `$.getJSON`.

All the AJAX request are handled by the `XMLHttpRequest` object of the browser. If this object receives a `redirect` response, it simply repeats the AJAX call to the given URL. That happens trasnparently, i.e. the `XHR` object doesn't notify in any way that it has done a redirect, so you cannot detect it in any way.

So, the short answer is that you cannot provoke a redirect in the browser via an AJAX call: it doesn't matter if it's Web API or MVC or traditional Web Forms, the problem is always that the `XHR` hides the redirects response, it simply uses it internally.

The long answer is that you can send an special response to the client, for example an object that can be recognized in the JavaScript AJAX client and use the traditional `window.location.href=*newUrl*` to force the redirect on the client.

For example you could implement a Web API method like this

```
public object GetRedirection()
{
   return new {
     redirect = true,
     newUrl = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
   };
}
```

And then invoke it and check the result, for example in this way:

```
$.getJSON('http://..../MyControler').done(function(result) {
  if (result.redirect) {
    window.location.href = result.newUrl;
  }
})
```

This is the only way to force a redirect with an AJAX client, i.e. indirectly.

*NOTE: of course, if you type the URL of the Web API in the browser address bar, and the invoked action returns a redirect response, it will redirect the browser. But I do suppose that you're using Web API with AJAX. You could also do a strange thing: use the same `window.location.href` code to invoke the Web API action that returnt the redirect.*